# Is it possible to log in to a SAML authenticated application using javascript and/or Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, saml

I'm attempting to make a custom client to a web service that is authenticated by SSO/SAML. So far I've tried following the redirects and set-cookies manually, but the redirects eventually got stuck in a loop. I also failed to recieve a set-cookie for "SimpleSAMLAuthToken", even though that cookie was present when looking through it in the browser.

If anyone finds it helpful I'm using Electron to make the application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible, you could try Okta

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-saml